# FTP - from one server to backup server - centos 7

Tags: ftp, centos7

I want to back up my server data to backup server space allotted to me, I am only allowed to do FTP. SFTP or SCP are not the option.

I am trying this way

```
ftp -n backup.server.net
Trying 62.210.xx.xx...
Connected to backup.server.net (62.210.xx.xx).
220 server ready - login please
ftp> user xxxx yyyy
331 password required
230 login accepted
ftp> put /var/www/html/index.php
local: /var/www/html/index.php remote: /var/www/html/index.php
227 Entering Passive Mode (62,210,xx,xx,xx,xxx)
553 Can't open that file: No such file or directory
ftp> get /var/www/html/index.php
local: ./var/www/html/index.php remote: /var/www/html/index.php
local: ./var/www/html/index.php: No such file or directory
ftp>
```

But its not working, please see and suggest any possible way to do it.

Thanks

**Update**

I can upload from `/root` but not from other directories and  I can only upload from other directories if I switch to directory first before ftp

```
ftp> put index-root.php
local: index-root.php remote: index-root.php
227 Entering Passive Mode (62,210,xx,xx,xx,xx)
150 Accepted data connection
226 File successfully transferred
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (62,210,xx,xx,xx,xx)
150 Accepted data connection
-rw-r--r--    1 1001       ftp                 0 Dec  7 11:10 index-root.php
226 1 matches total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `cd` to navigate the backup server filesystem and

use `lcd` to navigate the local filesystem

Comment: This is working, Is there any way around in which I do not have to change local dir, i.e I can just upload from anywhere.

Comment: You may use absolue paths in source and destination. `put /path/to/file /remote/destination/filename`

Answer (score 1):

Use mput or mget if you want to upload/download a file with it's full path.

Example below

**mput /var/www/html/index.php**

Hope this helps

Comment: Still not working `ftp> mput /var/www/html/index.php
mput /var/www/html/index.php?
227 Entering Passive Mode (62,210,xx,xx,xx,xxx)
553 Can't open that file: No such file or directory
ftp>`

Comment: Does this file exists on your client machine /var/www/html/index.php ?. what is the output of pwd command ?.

Comment: @serverlivind.com yes file exists and output of pwd is `/root`

Comment: It should work actually mput /var/www/html/index.php . Either there is some issue with your server environment or permissions.

Comment: @serverlivind.com I can upload from `/root` but not from other directories.

Comment: @serverlivind.com I can only upload from other directories if I switch to directory first before ftp